# "currently no loaders are configured to process this file" in Next.js for js files

Tags: webpack, next.js

I'm trying to migrate a next.js project to another next.js project. I do so because we're splitting a large project into smaller ones.

I receive this error:

```
../Project/components/Shared/AdminPanel/ButtonChip.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (17:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     }
| 
>     return <div
|         onClick={() => handleClick()}
|         className={"flex justify-between items-center gap-1.5 border border-gray-300 rounded-3xl px-3.5 py-1.5 lg:py-1 lg:gap-1.5 lg:px-2.5 " + className}
```

And here's my `next.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['www.amlakbashi.com'],
  },

  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    })

    return config
  }
}
```

Why do I get this error? Why `.js` files?

Comment: Have you tried converting your file extension to `.jsx`, i.e. `ButtonChip.jsx`?